# Automatically scrolling to anchor after submit

Tags: php, html

I have this little chatbox on my website with height of 450 pixels and overflow scroll. Now when user send a message and the page is refreshed, both the old and the new messages are shown. But when the page refreshes user needs to scroll down to see the latest message. How could I change this so that when the page refreshes the div is always automatically scrolled to the bottom?

Comment: This question is not related to Java.

Comment: Give the div an id, www.thisurl.com/page.ext#id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include a hash on the URL, and there's an element with a matching `id`, the browser will scroll down to it after loading the page. E.g.: `http://example.com#x123456` will scroll down to `<div id="x123456">...</div>`.